# Rails 3: ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I'm following [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3) here for sending mails from my rails app.

At first I tried to set up a mail interceptor like in the tutorial, but I've given up on that, because I always got a lovely `can't convert nil into Hash (TypeError)`.

Now that I left out the interceptor, I wanted to actually send a mail, but guess what - my old friend is back:

```
can't convert nil into Hash (TypeError)

app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:20:in `registration'
```

Here's the mailer class (line #20 is the one with the call to mail):

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def registration( user )
    @invited = user

    subject = 'Welcome!'

    if Rails.env.development?
      to = 'my.private@email.com'
      subject = "to #{@invited.email}: #{subject}"
    else
      to = @invited.email   
    end

    logger.info "Sending email to #{to} with subject #{subject}"

    mail( :from => 'noreply@mysite.com', :to => to, :subject => subject )
  end
end
```

The log shows:

```
invite entered for user foo@bar.com
Sending email to foo@bar.com
Sending email to my.private@email.com with subject to foo@bar.com: Welcome!
```

And here's the requested view file (registration.text.erb):

```
Welcome!

blablah blah click the following link to activate blah blah <%= activate_user_path( @invited )%> blah blah.
blah blah this is actually german (but plaintext) encoded in utf-8.
```

Viel Vergnügen beim Verwenden des Systems!

thx for any help

Comment: and I think that your `user` is `nil`

Comment: #20 is the one with the call to mail(...)

Comment: nope user isn't nil here, the log actually displays the correct data.

Comment: how did you call your `registration` method from controller?

Comment: The controller calls invite() on the user object, which does some user-stuff and then calls `UserMailer.registration( self ).deliver`

Comment: And show your VIEW file (/app/views/user_mailers/registration.html.erb or text.erb)

Comment: everything looks fine for you. check out your environment (rails and its dependencies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did it, I had an error in actionmailer's config

Comment: I am being bugged by the same error for a while. If you recall, can you mention what was the error for you?